# Assign a class to first element in category in loop

Tags: categories, loop, query-posts

I am trying to do the following:

1) assign `col-lg-4` class to the first element in the loop, when there are 3 or more posts within the given category.

2) assign `col-lg-8` class to the first element in the loop, when there are 2 posts within the given category.

3) leave the `col-sm-12` class on the first element in the loop, when there is only one post within the given category.

And so, here's what I thought of:

```
<div class="container special-offer-wrap">
    <div class="row special-offer-wrap special-offer-row">
        <?php
            $columns_query_args = array(
                'category_name' => 'featured',
                'posts_per_page' => '3'
            )
        ?>
        <?php $columns_query = new WP_Query( $columns_query_args ); ?>
        <?php if ( $columns_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( $columns_query->have_posts() ) : $columns_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-sm-12
                    <?php if( $columns_query_item_number == 0){
                        if( $the_query->found_posts == 1 ){
                        echo ' ';
                        }  else {
                            if( $the_query->found_posts == 2 ){
                            echo 'col-lg-8';
                            }  else {
                            echo 'col-lg-4';
                           }
                        }
                        } else echo 'col-lg-4'; /*all other posts */
                        $columns_query_item_number++;  ?>">
                    <div class="special-offer-description">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <?php the_excerpt( ); ?>
                    </div>                         
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'fresh_spring' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this, when there are 3 posts within the category:

[image]

The problem is that it doesn't change to the one similar to this:

[image]

when I come back to 2 posts within the category (by removing the category from the 3rd post), but instead it keeps the `col-lg-4` class on the first element.

Any ideas? I guess I messed something up with the query conditions.

EDIT:

On the suggestion by @Michael, I used debugging mode which showed me some problems with defining the variable `$columns_query_item_number`. Now it is defined properly and the only notice I get is the one about `woocommerce_get_page_id` being deprecated (although I don't have it right on my site, only in debug.log file, so I don't bother yet).

The other thing I did is that I changed `$the_query` to `$columns_query`, which right away got me to the solution, but the problem now is that the next loop has been compromised somehow. I don't really know why because the loop is reset at the end by `wp_reset_postdata()` function.

Comment: simple mistake: your loop is based on `$columns_query` while you are using `$the_query` in your conditional ... to get warnings and error messages, while developing your site, try and enable DEBUG https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: I followed your tips and some problems still hold, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

If `wp_reset_postdata()` doesn't work as expected you can backup the original `$post` object by inserting

```
global $post; // if you aren't in global scope
$postBk=$post;
```

before doing your WP_Query and restore it with

```
$post=$postBk;
```

right after `wp_reset_postdata();`

Comment: Now the code there looks like this:

<?php
                global $post;
                $postBk=$post;
                $columns_query_item_number = 0;
?>
...
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php $post=$postBk; ?> And it doesn't work still...

Comment: Now it works, although I don't see difference in code.
<?php global $post; $postBk=$post; $columns_query_item_number = 0; $columns_query_args = array( 'category_name' => 'featured', 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) $columns_query = new WP_Query( $columns_query_args ); if ( $columns_query->have_posts() ) : ?> SOME CODE HERE <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> <?php else : ?> <p>code here</p> <?php endif; ?> <a href=""></a> <?php $post=$postBk;
?>